# The number of roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Let $F$ be a field and $f\in F[x]$ of degree $d$. We know that in general, the number of roots of $f$ is not always less than or equal to $d$. For example, $F$ is the field $F$ is The quaternion field $\mathbb{H}$ and $f=x^2+1$ has infinitely many roots in $\mathbb{H}$.

But if the field $F$ is commutative, the number of roots of $f$ is less than or equal to $d$ indeed:

By induction on $d$. For $d = 0$, a nonzero constant polynomial obviously has zero roots.

Let $d$ be fixed, suppose the result true for polynomials of degree $d$; let $f$ now be a polynomial of degree $d+ 1$. If $f$ has no root, the result is true for $f$; otherwise either $\alpha$ a root of $f$, we can write $f = (x-\alpha)g$ for a polynomial $g$, which is clearly of degree $d$. Now, if $\beta$ is a root of $f$, then $0 = f(\beta)=(\beta-\alpha)g(\beta)$ so $ \beta=\alpha$ or $\beta$ is a root of $g$; but $g$ has at most $d$ roots, so $f$ has at most $d + 1$.

But in my proof, I don't see interest of commutativity of the field. no ? Can someone help me please?

Comment: Well have you tried what step goes wrong when you try to apply this to $f=x^2+1$ over $\mathbb H$? It is a bit hard to see at first, but as a hint, six of the quaternionic solutions to $x^2+1=0$ are $\pm \mathbf{i}, \pm \mathbf{j}, \pm \mathbf{k}$. Now: plugging e.g. the quaternion $\mathbf j$ into $x^2+1$ gives what, whereas plugging it into $(x+\mathbf{i} ) (x- \mathbf{i})$ gives what?

Comment: plugging quaternion $j$ into $x^2+1$ gives $0$, while plugging it into $(x+i)(x−i)$ gives $2k$. But, what can we conclude from this?

Comment: That "plugging values into a polynomial" does not necessarily commute with "factoring a polynomial" when we are over a non-commutative ring. That, in particular, $f=(x-\alpha) g$ does not imply $f(\beta) = (\beta -\alpha)g(\beta)$ in your proof if the ground ring is not commutative.

Comment: Ah yes I understood now, it is a problem of substitution in the polynomial. Thanks very much .